# Merging data from different Observables, and choosing different fetching strategies, depending on data availability

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, observable

I have a situation, in which, by fetching an `Item` object, one of three things should happen:

- If the item is not present in cache (a.k.a is null), then load data from both `api1`, and `api2`, merge the data and return an `Observable`.
- If the item is present in cache, but a certain piece of it is missing, load data from `api2`, and merge it with the already available data in the cache
- if the entire data is available in the cache, simply return it.

So far, this is the best that I have managed to come up with:

```
val cacheObservable = cache.fetchItem(itemId);
val api1Observable = api1.fetchItem(itemId);
val api2Observable = api2.fetchItem(itemId);

val resultObservable = cacheObservable!!.flatMap { item: Item? ->
    if (item == null) {
        /* Get the item data, and the full text separately, then combine them */
        Observable.zip(api1Observable, api2Observable, { itemData, itemText ->
            itemData.apply { text = itemText }
        });
    } else if (item.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        /* Get the full text only, then add it to the already cached version */
        cacheObservable.zipWith(api2Observable, { cachedItem, itemText -> cachedItem.apply { text = itemText; } });
    } else {
        /* if the data and the full text are provided, simply return */
        Observable.just(item);
    }
}.doOnNext { item -> cache.saveOrUpdateItem(item); }

return resultObservable;
```

This works OK, so far, but I have been wondering, if there is a more declarative way to achieve the same effect. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your ```fetchItem``` function can return an error instead of ```null```, so you can use error handling operators instead of checking for null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Kotlin syntax, but here is a Java example that you can translate. It requires `cache.fetchItem(itemId)` to complete instead of emitting a `null` when the item is not in the cache.

If `cacheFetch` emits an item, the `flatMap()` will ensure that the item has the text and fetch it from the network if needed.

If there is nothing in cache, `fullFetch` will get it from the network.

`concatWith(fullFetch).take(1)` will ensure that `fullFetch` is only subscribed to if there is nothing in cache.

The item is only saved to cache if it was updated.

```
Observable<Item> cacheFetch = cache.fetchItem(itemId);
Observable<Item> fullFetch =
  Observable
    .zip(
      api1.fetchItem(itemId),
      api2.fetchItem(itemId),
      (item, itemText) -> {
          item.text = itemText;
          return item;
      })
    .doOnNext(cache::saveOrUpdateItem);

Observable<Item> resultObservable =
  cacheFetch
    .flatMap(item -> {
      if (item.text != null && !item.text.isEmpty()) {
        return Observable.just(item);
      }
      return api2
        .fetchItem(itemId)
        .map(itemText -> {
          item.text = itemText;
          return item;
        })
        .doOnNext(cache::saveOrUpdateItem);
    })
    .concatWith(fullFetch)
    .take(1);
  }
```